# jQuery change to return checked or unchecked status

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, return, onchange

I'm trying to use the following function to return `true` or `false`, based on the status of a checkbox, I'm using the `jQuery` `iButton` plugin (that hides the checkbox and replace it by an `iPhone` style  sliding button that supports dragging event) the only way I found to detect the dragging as well as the click event is using jQuery change.

```
var testChecked= function(){
    $('#status').change(function(){ // #status is the checkbox ID
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            console.log('is_checked');//works
            return true;
        }
        else{
            console.log('is_unchecked');//works
            return false 
        } 
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fnt5J/1/

Comment: Please create an jsFiddle with your problem, makes helping you alot easier.

Comment: `var testChecked= function(){ return $("#status").is(':checked'); };`?

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply http://jsfiddle.net/fnt5J/1/
All I'm trying to do is making this function return true or false once executed

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea what is `status` in your code.

As you have mentioned iButton jQuery plugin, I found this page after googling about this. http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm

I've just typed the this `$('#iButton').attr('checked');`  statement in chrome console and I got the correct status as `true` or `false` based on the ON and OFF status.

So i think you have to do the following thing in your code.

```
$('#status').change(function(){
    return $('#iButton').attr('checked');
})
```

Comment: if you type the same thing on FF console it wont return false.
http://jsfiddle.net/fnt5J/1/

Comment: I've no idea why you've wrapped change event inside a function testChecked. I've removed that and now its logging. Please check. http://jsfiddle.net/fnt5J/2/

Answer (score 0):

In iButton jQuery Plug-in there are a number of options available, so you can use a event handlers: change.

```
$('#ibutton').iButton({
  change: function (){
    if($('#ibutton').attr('checked'))
       console.log("TRUE");
    else
       console.log("FALSE");
  }
});
```